# How can I dynamically add <input type="text" values into a <select> as an <option>?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with a dropdown menu and a text field. The idea is that when the user clicks "submit" the value they entered goes into the dropdown. I've been working with code off of a [TryIt Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_add) on [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/).

Here is the code I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <form>
    <select id="mySelect">
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Pear</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>Orange</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <br>

  <p>Click the button to add a "Kiwi" option at the end of the dropdown list.</p>

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Insert option</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = "Kiwi";
      x.add(option);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

In frustration i reverted back to the original code on the TryIt editor. Thanks for help!

Comment: What's PHP got to do with this?

Comment: @j08691 I would have to guess that they are asking "Give me teh PHP codez"

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using a different site/resource for your learning. And in terms of asking a question, you should tell us what the _expected_ result is, what the _actual_ result is, and what you have already done to debug/resolve the issue.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't have a text field...

Comment: So far I've been trying with PHP

Comment: @NickParsons I know... I reverted back to the original in frustration to try and start over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a textbox and let the user enter a value into that textbox to add to the dropdown list you can add a few additional lines of code (see comments in fiddle):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <form>
    <select id="mySelect">
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Pear</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>Orange</option>
    </select>
    
    <input type="text" id="txt" placeholder="fruit"/> <!-- Add textbox for UI -->
  </form>
  <br>

  <p>Click the button to add a "Kiwi" option at the end of the dropdown list.</p>

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Insert option</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
      var input = document.getElementById("txt"); // Get the textbox element
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = input.value; // Get the value in the textbox element
      x.add(option);
      input.value = ""; // Set the text-box back to blank
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you and Being Sunny saved me hours of googling!

Comment: No worries!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple have you tried like this way? just add a new text element on your html section like this `<input type="text" id="text_box" />` and get the value using the element `ID`. Just **Run Code Snippet** and I Hope this will help you.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var input_box = document.getElementById("text_box");
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = input_box.value;
  x.add(option);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form>
    <select id="mySelect" size="8">
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Pear</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>Orange</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="text_box" />
  <p>Click the button to add textbox's text as an option at the end of the dropdown list.</p>

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Insert option</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer and Nick Parsons' answer both work great!

Comment: @CheesyPotato glad it helps you somehow..by the way see this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I would take to append an `<option>` to the `<select>`. Check out the comments in the code.

```js
//reference to your button element
var button = document.querySelector('button');
//add a click listener that calls a handler function
button.addEventListener('click', addOption);

//the handler function below will add an element to the select
function addOption() {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = "Kiwi";
  //use "appendChild", not "add"
  document.getElementById('mySelect').appendChild(option);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <form>
    <select id="mySelect">
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Pear</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>Orange</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <br>

  <p>Click the button to add a "Kiwi" option at the end of the dropdown list.</p>

  <button type="button">Insert option</button>

  <script>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="text_field" />
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Insert option</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
        var textField = document.getElementById("text_field");
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = textField.value;
        // option.value = textField.value; // You'll probably need to do this too
        x.add(option);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the jQuery version

```
$('#mySelect').append($('<option>', {
  value: 1,
  text: 'My option'
}));
```

hope this help you.